# jQuery updated values not getting new value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to make table inline editable through jQuery. When I press the edit button table row become editable previous values are also showed in text fields. But when I enter new values and press save button I do not get updated values and database also remain unchanged.

Code to get previous values to show in editable table row is:

```
var nam =$("#name_"+id).html();
```

code to make table row editable is:

```
$("#name_"+id).html("<input type='text' name='name' id='name_"+id+"' value='"+nam+"'>");
```

code to get updated values:

```
var nm = $('#name_'+id+'').text();
```

ajax request to update database:

```
url: "inlineUpdate.php?id="+id+"name="+nm,
```

Comment: check in network tab of console and check what it shows as the response for inlineUpdate.php

you should seperate both parameters that you are passing

Comment: when save button is pressed after entering values and when i refresh refresh page that updated row becomes blank means blank values are passed to ajax request.
No error is thrown .

Comment: when you click save button,check in network tab of console by pressing F12

Comment: please separate your parameters with &. 
or try type:'post' in ajax call

Comment: @MUHAMMADFIAZ `.val()` instead of `.text()` to get update value, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Point #1:: ID correction***

`"name_"+id` is pointing two elements at same time, a `<input>` and table row that contains the `<input>`. so for `input` ID, instead of using `"name_"+id` twice, you must use some other ID. eg. `"name_"+id+"_editable"` and use that to get update value.

***Point #2:: Get update value***

`var nm = $('#name_'+id+'_editable').val();`

Here,as its a `<input>` field, so need to use `.val()`, not `.text()`;

***Point #3:: AJAX parameter passing***

`url: "inlineUpdate.php?id="+id+"name="+nm,`

to

`url: "inlineUpdate.php?id="+id+"&name="+nm,`

```
                                ^----------- missed this (&)
```

Comment: that thing I already told him. But I think he is missing something more.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input field id to something else like (there can't be same id for two elements)

```
$("#name_"+id).html("<input type='text' name='name' id='name_"+id+"_input' value='"+nam+"'>");
```

use that name to get the value

```
var nm = $('#name_'+id+'_input').val();
```